# Will the Japan Indonesia friendship Festival 2014 be held despite dengue outbreak?

Tags: health, tokyo, festivals, events

This event is planned to happen on Sunday at Yoyogi Park Event Area:
[Japan Attractions](http://japan-attractions.jp/food/the-6th-japan-indonesia-citizen-friendship-festival-2014/)

But I have heard that part of Yoyogi Park is closed due to a dengue fever outbreak:
[The Japan Times](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2014/09/04/national/tokyo-closes-part-yoyogi-park-dengue-carrying-mosquitoes-found)

Will the event be held?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancellation of the event was announced on September 5.

[J Cast](http://www.j-cast.com/2014/09/05215127.html)

Answer (score 1):

As of September 4, the event will be held according to this document on the festival's website:

[Indonesia Festival](http://indonesia-festival.com/dengue%20matter.pdf)

Note: Their website has invalid SSL certificate.

It says the event is held but they will have anti-mosquito coils around, and people should wear long sleeves.